# Upgrading to Craft 4 dosen’t seem to work

Tags: upgrades, craft4

I went through the upgrade guide step-by-step and all went smoothly without error. But my Craft Installation is still running in 3.7.57. I logged out and in again, it still runs Craft 3. Also repeated the last steps of the guide.

I did the upgrade on an online instance and not locally, could that be the problem?

Does anyone knows that issue? Any ideas on what I could try?

Answer (score 2):

Have your `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files been updated with the new versions for Craft and all your plugins/dependencies? You should be able to tell by looking at the version of Craft that's required in your `composer.json` - it should look something like this:

`"craftcms/cms": "^4.0.0"`

If that semver number is still starting with a `3` (e.g. `"^3.6.0"`) or just has a number in it and no `^` (e.g. `"3.6.0"`) prefix, then Composer can't upgrade you to Craft 4.

If it is set to Craft 4, I'd try deleting your `vendor` directory and running `composer install` again, then clear all caches.

Comment: Yay thanks for the hint. Done that but somehow it changed it back. Deleted composer.lock and that made the trick for me. Thanks for the answer, led me to the right direction.